# How to choose colClasses in read.csv.ffdf?

Tags: r, csv

How should I choose colClasses arg of read.csv.ffdf in order to input NA values if there is such in integer columns?

And later on I need to convert that class to numeric so I can calculate...

I succed with read.csv, but it does not help because I have huge data and I need faster way (read.csv.ffdf).

Example of my problem below:

```
b1 <- read.csv("file.csv", header=TRUE, colClasses="character")
g <- b1$numeric.column
g1 <- type.convert(g, na.strings = "NA", as.is = FALSE, dec = ".", numerals = "allow.loss")
g1 <- g1[!is.na(g1)]
mean(g1) #this one is ok


a1 <- read.csv.ffdf(file="file.csv", header=TRUE, VERBOSE=TRUE, first.rows=1000, next.rows=700000, colClasses="factor")
h <- a1$numeric.column
h1 <- as.numeric(h)
h1
numeric(0) #is not converted to numeric
h11 <- as.integer(h)
h11
integer(0)
```

Is there any other way to input numeric column (from huge csv data) **eventhough there are few NA values**? And then use that values as numeric...

Thanks!